# Change teaser template based on a field

Tags: theming, 8

I have a drop down in my article content type which lets the user select which teaser template to use for that article.

I'm trying to change the template in `themename_preprocess_node()`, since this is where I know what template is assigned to that specific article.

My problem is that I am struggling to specify which twig template to render.

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the template in preprocess, there's a separate hook for that, `hook_theme_suggestions_template()`

This is what node is doing for the node template:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK().
 */
function node_theme_suggestions_node(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = array();
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
  $sanitized_view_mode = strtr($variables['elements']['#view_mode'], '.', '_');

  $suggestions[] = 'node__' . $sanitized_view_mode;
  $suggestions[] = 'node__' . $node->bundle();
  $suggestions[] = 'node__' . $node->bundle() . '__' . $sanitized_view_mode;
  $suggestions[] = 'node__' . $node->id();
  $suggestions[] = 'node__' . $node->id() . '__' . $sanitized_view_mode;

  return $suggestions;
}
```

You can provide something similar. Note that when you do this in a template, you have to use the alter hook, like this example from the bartik theme:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter() for form templates.
 */
function bartik_theme_suggestions_form_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#form_id'] == 'search_block_form') {
    $suggestions[] = 'form__search_block_form';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Berdir, this has definitely pushed me in the correct direction - I will mark your answer as correct - and also post my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I ended up adding a theme suggestion based on a field (`field_teaser_template`) from the article.

```
  /**
   * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter() for node templates.
   */
  function themename_theme_suggestions_node_alter(array &$suggestions, array $vars) {
    $node = $vars['elements']['#node'];

    if ($node->hasField('field_teaser_template') && $node->field_teaser_template->value) {
      $template_name = $node->field_teaser_template->value;
      $suggestions[] = 'node__teaser__' . $template_name;
    }
    return $suggestions;
  }
```

Comment: Note that $node->field_teaser_template->value will fail if a node doesn't have that field. Remove the isset(), that doesn't really help, instead check with hasField: $node->hasField('field_teaser_template') && $node->field_teaser_template->value. Also, you might want to enforce a certain prefix for you templates, like 'node__teaser__' . $template_name. I guess your field is a list field, but still, someone might end up adding user or something completely else in there and it would use a completely unrelated template...

Comment: Thank you for your improvements - much appreciated. I will amend my post above to include your suggestions, in case someone else finds it helpful.